# Converting 2D viewport translation to 3D rotation

Tags: c#, wpf, math, 3d, geometry

I am trying to rotate a 3D Cylinder with reference to a 2D viewport. With the radius of the cylinder and the 2D translation known, how can i find out the angle it turns?

[image: Illustration of what i want to find out]

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about your situation and what specifically you are trying to achieve. It's not clear how you want to be rotation and translation to be related.

Comment: @KendallFrey I have edited my post with an illustration hope you understand what i meant. Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to find appropriate search terms for a 2D-3D mapping, the usual term is "unproject", which reverse-walks a 2D construct (usually a point-ray) into a 3D ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the cylinder rotates from A to B. Further, let's assume that A is `θ` degrees counterclockwise and B is `θ` degrees clockwise from the horizontal. Thus, the angle between A and B is `2θ`.

The y coordinate of A is given by `r*sin(θ)`, that of B is simply `-r*sin(θ)`.

Thus, `2*r*sin(θ) = D` (the pan distance)

Solve for `θ`:

```
θ = asin(D/(2*r))
```

(where asin is the arc sine function)

Another (possibly more robust) method would be to compute the perpendicular and base of the triangle and then do an `atan2(perp,base)`.

The perpendicular is simply `D/2`, while the base is `sqrt(R*R - D*D/4)`.

Comment: Wouldn't the formula you use depend on the [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection) you use?

Comment: Absolutely! Good point, @ScottChamberlain. I'm assuming this is for one of those "wheel" widgets like this one: http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html

Comment: @RahulBanerjee Thanks! Your formula seems to work great for my case. I am actually doing a 3D carousel with touch. Implementing it with Touch manipulation and inertia.

Comment: Glad I guessed (almost) correctly! Thanks for the feedback :)